# Counting parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

What the docs at Mozilla says:

```
  console.log((function(...args) {}).length); 
  // 0, rest parameter is not counted

  console.log((function(a, b = 1, c) {}).length);
  // 1, only parameters before the first one with 
  // a default value is counted
```

So how will I ever be able to count parameters in such cases ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length

Comment: Counting the number of parameters outside the function or counting the number of arguments passed to the function?

Comment: Why do you need to count parameters? And why does your title say "*number of arguments*"? Those are different things.

Comment: Why would you ever care about the number of parameters?

Comment: If you need to define some alternate criteria for counting the number of parameters, you'll need to parse the function signature yourself.

Comment: @Bergi I am learning JS and there is nothing wrong in exploring everything , in the future I may require it ! :)

Comment: @TilakMaddy coding for 20 years and I have not required that. ;)

Comment: FYI, there is a difference between counting the _expected_ length of the arguments and the length of arguments passed...

Comment: @epascarello since you are a bad fisherman (as your profile says), you must wait some more time to catch fish XD

Comment: The described problem is the main reason why relying on function signature in JS is antipattern.

Comment: @TilakMaddy No, you should not require that, it's a bad practice to let functionality depend on the number of parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two separate things going on here with **parameters defined** and **arguments actually passed**.

For a defined function, you can get access to the number of parameters that are defined in the definition of the function with `fn.length`:

```
function talk(greeting, delay) {
    // some code here
}

console.log(talk.length);     // shows 2 because there are two defined parameters in 
                              // the function definition
```

Separately, from within a function, you can see how many arguments are actually passed to a function for a given invocation of that function using `arguments.length`.  Suppose you had a function that was written to accept an optional callback as the last argument:

```
function talk(greeting, delay, callback) {
    console.log(arguments.length);     // shows how many arguments were actually passed
}

talk("hello", 200);    // will cause the function to show 2 arguments are passed
talk("hello", 200, function() {    // will show 3 arguments are passed
     console.log("talk is done now");
});
```

Comment: For your second solution, couldn't one _**just count the parameters passed in**_ when invoked?

Comment: @Pineda - What do you mean ***count***?  Why count them when `arguments.length` gives you the number directly?  I suppose you could iterate over the `arguments` object to see how many properties it has, but I don't see the point when `arguments.length` already contains the desired count.

Comment: I was referring to the way that the OP was trying to achieve this from outside of the function.  I trying to suggest an edit to show the usefulness of the `arguments` _within_ the function rather than outside of it.

Comment: 'There are two separate things going on here with arguments defined and arguments actually passed' - that's why we have different terms for them. 'arguments actually passed' are *arguments*, and 'arguments defined' are *parameters*.

Comment: @estus - I updated my answer to use the proper terms.